# vb.net INSERT CURDATE() to MySQL issue

Tags: mysql, vb.net, insert, windows

In a windows application I have a query that im trying to insert the current date on my mysql database

query below:

```
SqlVentaCasas1 = "INSERT INTO VentaCasasHistory (ID, Direccion, Estatus, Precio, " & _
                                "NumeroDias, FechaHoy, Agente, Compania, Unidad, Ciudad ) VALUES ('" & _
                                AddIDCasas2 & "','" & AddDireccionCasas2 & "','" & AddEstatusCasas2 & "'," & AddPrecioCasas2 & ", 0, CURDATE(), '" & AgenteNameCasas2 & "','" & AgenteCompaniaCasas2 & "', '" & AddUnidadCasas2 & "', '" & AddCiudadCasas2 & "' );"


                        CommandVentaCasas1 = New MySqlCommand(SqlVentaCasas1, con)
                        CommandVentaCasas1.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                        CommandVentaCasas1.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

when i input the values that i want to insert into mysql everything runs smoothly except that when i check the database for the date entered i find myself with the 0000-00-00

on the other hand, when i run the same query from PHPmyAdmin

```
INSERT INTO `VentaCasasHistory`(`ID`, `Direccion`, `Estatus`, `Precio`, `NumeroDias`, `FechaHoy`, `Agente`, `Compania`, `Unidad`, `Ciudad`) VALUES ([String1],[String2],[String3],[Integer1],[Integer2],CURDATE(),[String4],[String5],[String6],[String7])
```

where FechaHoy is CURDATE() is does insert correctly the date that should be.

I cant seem to find what is the problem, As i understand it will only insert 0000-00-00 if there is something wrong with the date when been entered.

the reason i kept both queries "identical" was to understand what im doing wrong and I know that they can be subject to SQL injection.

your help would be very appreciated.

Leo P.

this is the code i have for the last piece that you told me.

```
Dim StringDate As String

    StringDate = Date.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

SqlVentaCasas1 = "INSERT INTO VentaCasasHistory (ID, Direccion, Estatus, Precio, " & _
                                "NumeroDias, FechaHoy, Agente, Compania, Unidad, Ciudad ) VALUES ('" & _
                                AddIDCasas2 & "','" & AddDireccionCasas2 & "','" & AddEstatusCasas2 & "'," & AddPrecioCasas2 & ", 0, STR_TO_DATE('" & StringDate & "', GET_FORMAT(DATE,'ISO')), '" & AgenteNameCasas2 & "','" & AgenteCompaniaCasas2 & "', '" & AddUnidadCasas2 & "', '" & AddCiudadCasas2 & "' );"
```

unfortunately it does not work and i still get the 0000-00-00.

Comment: One reason for using parameterized queries is to avoid injection attacks - another is because it allows you to specify the type of the arguments. 

Have you tried parameterizing and specifying the correct data type for the date field?

Also - can you step through the debugger and paste the final SQL query that it is running?

Comment: @Origin    </StackTrace><ExceptionString>MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Reading from the stream has failed. ---&amp;gt; System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CURDATE()` should really be specified as default value used in `CREATE TABLE`. In other words, you don't need to put it in as part of a query as when you insert a new record the field with default value set to `CURDATE()` will have the date automatically inserted.

F.ex:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    MyName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    MyDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURDATE(),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)

INSERT INTO MyTable (MyName) VALUES ('Epistemex')
```

Will set the `MyDate` field to `CURDATE()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: does help to understand hot to create tables but no how to insert data containing dates

Comment: I added an example of insert too - point is you don't need to supply date (for current date) when it's defined as a default in the table itself. If you look at my insert you will not see MyDate anywhere. This because it's taken care of automatically on the server (assuming CURDATE() is what you specifically is after).

Comment: There are some cases where one would want to provide the date though. If you're inserting 100,000 rows it would be a waste of resources to have the database calculate a date 100,000 times. Or, perhaps you want all the Entries for a report to show the same `DateCreated` value.

Comment: Sure, but in this case as CURDATE is used, doesn't matter if it's in a query or in default, it will have to be "calculated" anyways. That being said, personally I would prefer to feed the date myself from the software formatted as ISO-date (dim cacheDate as string =now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))

Comment: @Abdias Software Does this also apply to a windows application coded on vb.net ? the whole problem is that when i insert all the variables i do have to get the date into the table on the mysql. i have tried entering strings, dates like date.Today...etc, even i have tried SQL clauses like NOW() CURDATE().

Comment: @TopoX - Abdias's solution is a SQL one. The way it works is you set the table to default the field to the calculated CurDate() value, and don't provide that argument upon insertion. I still think you should try parameterizing the arguments and specifying their type. Though - the error you posted doesn't appear to have to do with insertion.

Comment: @TopoX How do you format the date? MySQL needs the date formatted as "ISO-date", that is: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, and they must be enclosded in single quotes, f.ex: ... VALUES ('2012-10-05')... -or- VALUES ('2012-10-05 08:10:23')... In VB you can format the date like this: MyDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") so in your query: ...& AddPrecioCasas2 & ", 0, '" & Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "', '" & ...

Comment: @AbdiasSoftware i have added the code as you suggested, on this specific table it does not work =\, I have another query "longer" which inserts a property to a database and includes a date that is grabbed from a date-picker, I have done the same steps to the last example i posted and this inserts the date. but when i try with that specific table/query it doesn't. i could provide the whole function code on a document since it is long.

Comment: If you could.. It's difficult to debug without it.

Comment: @AbdiasSoftware the following link is the AddCasas Function. it does include the problem im facing " http://www2.zshare.ma/itst74338teb "

Comment: As you have formatted StringDate into ISO-format already, you can actually insert the date directly as: ...0, '" & StringDate & "', '" & AgenteNameCasas2 & ... See if that works. If you still get zero's, change your StringDate line to: StringDate = Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")  (Happy b-day btw?)

Comment: @AbdiasSoftware thank you for the bday wishes, I made a small program testing the insert for that specific query the small one, it did work and i was able to insert the date, Now what i have noticed out of these is that running two queries one after the other is causing the second one to give 0000-00-00 in the date. is there a way to insert data in two tables using one query ?

Comment: @AbdiasSoftware i have solved the issue, the problem was i had another fuction that would run right after the insert, an "update fuction" which caused the 0000-00-00 to kick in. why do i have such a function "wasting resources", well for some reason when i add some variables at random times and when i search them with my program they do not appear and updating the DB solved that issue. :) thank you very much for your time and patience. and you are indeed right on all of the solutions you placed to me. I will work towards modifying my queries in the future to prevent SQL injections :)

Comment: That's excellent @TopoX :-) and no problem. Sometimes does small buggers hide well in plain sight.